# ScriptManager is inaccessible

Tags: javascript, asp.net, class, scriptmanager

I am trying to invoke the js function implemented on the aspx page from a .cs class. But, ScriptManager doesn't seem to exist in .cs class. Basically, the .cs file is a part of dll that I am using in my project. I need to invoke the js function that is implemented on the aspx page, from my .cs file present in the dll.

The js function is successfuly invoked from the aspx page, but when I try the same code in .cs file it says

> ScriptManager is inaccessible due to its protection level.

here is code I am trying

```
protected void MyMethod()
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", "jsfunction();", true);
}
```

any ideas why the same code runs successfuly on the aspx page but not from a .cs class?

Comment: If it only happen on your site, please try set  <trust level="Full" /> in you web.confg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to overcome the above issue I simply tried with this piece of code

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", "jsfunction();", true);
```

Notice the use of full namespace with ScriptManager.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript accept Page or Control as first argument. Make sure you pass your current Page to the cs method

```
protected void MyMethod(Page page)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(UpdatePanel), new Guid().ToString() , "jsfunction();", true);
}
```

And call from aspx.cs page using:

```
MyMethod(this.Page);
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, but now I'm facing another problem what I think is not a part of this question. Thanks Akhil